# How can I use the preprocessor to conditionally compile code based on platform or architecture?

Tags: c, linux, conditional-compilation

I am writing code that needs to run on multiple platforms or architectures, such as x86, ARM or MIPS.
I want to restrict or sometimes have to compile different part of the code for a specific architecture.

I tried using `#ifdef` to write code for a specific arch.

```
#ifdef ARM_TYPE
// Arm-specific code goes here
#else
// Unix/Linux-specific code goes here
#endif
```

Although it makes code to be rewritten.
Want to know if this can be handled better and if there any other ways to make this better?

Comment: Yes, `#ifdef` (or `#if`) is the most common way to do this. *"it makes code to be rewritten"* What does this mean?

Comment: Most of that could possibly be done using the build-system, where it is told to only build certain files on target A, and some other files for target B. If the source is suitably modular and using a common interface for all targets, then build those into libraries that can then be linked for the application.

Comment: On a side-note, "Unix/Linux" are operating systems, that can (and *do*) run on multiple hardware targets. Like ARM. Every Android phone is using Linux as the OS, and most are running on ARM hardware. You have to be careful to distinguish between "hardware" targets and "OS" targets. Your example mixes them.

Comment: Which compilers do you plan to use?

Comment: Hi theoretically the C language really ought to be platform independent, it's just how things turned out that we have to deal with varying systems. I've not read much on the topic and have problems with it myself. Some book say to create different c files and compile them separately, some books say to use ifdefs. Both have tradeoffs, either way we have to write different code according to the platform.

Answer (score 1):

With GCC, you can use `#ifdef __arm__`. Other compilers have other predefined macros. See https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home for more.